# What parameters can we specify along with it's acceptable options in CORSWithConfig using middleware in Echo Framework Golang custom configuration

Tags: go, cors, echo

What are the parameters and their acceptable values, and how to use `CORSWithConfig` custom configuration in middleware while using echo framework, in golang, to handle CORS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there are many other parameters. You can read about them [here](https://echo.labstack.com/middleware/cors/).

---

Configurations

```
CORSConfig struct {
  // Skipper defines a function to skip middleware.
  Skipper Skipper

  // AllowOrigin defines a list of origins that may access the resource.
  // Optional. Default value []string{"*"}.
  AllowOrigins []string `yaml:"allow_origins"`

  // AllowOriginFunc is a custom function to validate the origin. It takes the
  // origin as an argument and returns true if allowed or false otherwise. If
  // an error is returned, it is returned by the handler. If this option is
  // set, AllowOrigins is ignored.
  // Optional.
  AllowOriginFunc func(origin string) (bool, error) `yaml:"allow_origin_func"`

  // AllowMethods defines a list methods allowed when accessing the resource.
  // This is used in response to a preflight request.
  // Optional. Default value DefaultCORSConfig.AllowMethods.
  AllowMethods []string `yaml:"allow_methods"`

  // AllowHeaders defines a list of request headers that can be used when
  // making the actual request. This is in response to a preflight request.
  // Optional. Default value []string{}.
  AllowHeaders []string `yaml:"allow_headers"`

  // AllowCredentials indicates whether or not the response to the request
  // can be exposed when the credentials flag is true. When used as part of
  // a response to a preflight request, this indicates whether or not the
  // actual request can be made using credentials.
  // Optional. Default value false.
  AllowCredentials bool `yaml:"allow_credentials"`

  // ExposeHeaders defines a whitelist headers that clients are allowed to
  // access.
  // Optional. Default value []string{}.
  ExposeHeaders []string `yaml:"expose_headers"`

  // MaxAge indicates how long (in seconds) the results of a preflight request
  // can be cached.
  // Optional. Default value 0.
  MaxAge int `yaml:"max_age"`
}
```

---

Example Usage

```
e := echo.New()
e.Use(middleware.CORSWithConfig(middleware.CORSConfig{
  AllowOrigins: []string{"https://labstack.com", "https://labstack.net"},
  AllowHeaders: []string{echo.HeaderOrigin, echo.HeaderContentType, 
echo.HeaderAccept},
}))
```

---

Default

```
DefaultCORSConfig = CORSConfig{
  Skipper:      DefaultSkipper,
  AllowOrigins: []string{"*"},
  AllowMethods: []string{http.MethodGet, http.MethodHead, http.MethodPut, http.MethodPatch, http.MethodPost, http.MethodDelete},
}
```

Comment: Weird that `AllowOriginFunc` has a YAML field tag... I wonder how it's supposed to work with a function...

Answer (score -1):

Here's a sample on how we can use CORSWithConfig
and all the possible values we can use with AllowHeaders, ExposeHeaders, and AllowMethods.

```
app := echo.New()

    app.Use(middleware.CORSWithConfig(middleware.CORSConfig{
        AllowOrigins: []string{"http://127.0.0.1:5173", "wails://wails.localhost:34115", "http://127.0.0.1:5174"},
        // AllowOrigins:     []string{"*"},
        AllowHeaders:     []string{echo.HeaderOrigin, echo.HeaderContentType, echo.HeaderAccept, echo.HeaderAccessControlAllowOrigin, echo.HeaderAccessControlAllowCredentials, echo.HeaderAccessControlAllowHeaders, echo.HeaderAccessControlAllowMethods, echo.HeaderAccessControlExposeHeaders, echo.HeaderAccessControlMaxAge, echo.HeaderAccessControlRequestHeaders, echo.HeaderAccessControlRequestMethod, echo.HeaderAuthorization, echo.HeaderContentLength, echo.HeaderContentSecurityPolicy, echo.HeaderContentType, echo.HeaderCookie, echo.HeaderLastModified, echo.HeaderLocation, echo.HeaderOrigin, echo.HeaderServer, echo.HeaderSetCookie, echo.HeaderStrictTransportSecurity, echo.HeaderUpgrade, echo.HeaderVary, echo.HeaderWWWAuthenticate, echo.HeaderXContentTypeOptions, echo.HeaderXCSRFToken, echo.HeaderXFrameOptions, echo.HeaderXRequestID, echo.HeaderXRequestedWith, echo.HeaderXForwardedFor, echo.HeaderXForwardedProto, echo.HeaderXRealIP, echo.HeaderXCSRFToken},
        AllowCredentials: true,
        // ExposeHeaders:    []string{"*"},
        ExposeHeaders: []string{echo.HeaderOrigin, echo.HeaderContentType, echo.HeaderAccept, echo.HeaderAccessControlAllowOrigin, echo.HeaderAccessControlAllowCredentials, echo.HeaderAccessControlAllowHeaders, echo.HeaderAccessControlAllowMethods, echo.HeaderAccessControlExposeHeaders, echo.HeaderAccessControlMaxAge, echo.HeaderAccessControlRequestHeaders, echo.HeaderAccessControlRequestMethod, echo.HeaderAuthorization, echo.HeaderContentLength, echo.HeaderContentSecurityPolicy, echo.HeaderContentType, echo.HeaderCookie, echo.HeaderLastModified, echo.HeaderLocation, echo.HeaderOrigin, echo.HeaderServer, echo.HeaderSetCookie, echo.HeaderStrictTransportSecurity, echo.HeaderUpgrade, echo.HeaderVary, echo.HeaderWWWAuthenticate, echo.HeaderXContentTypeOptions, echo.HeaderXCSRFToken, echo.HeaderXFrameOptions, echo.HeaderXRequestID, echo.HeaderXRequestedWith, echo.HeaderXForwardedFor, echo.HeaderXForwardedProto, echo.HeaderXRealIP, echo.HeaderXCSRFToken, "X-User-Id", "X-User-Email", "X-User-Name", "X-User-Role", "X-User-Permissions", "X-User-Groups", "X-User-Scopes", "X-User-Sub", "X-Set-Cookie", "X-Set-Cookie-Expires", "X-Set-Cookie-Max-Age", "X-Set-Cookie-Path", "X-Set-Cookie-Domain", "X-Set-Cookie-Secure", "X-Set-Cookie-HttpOnly", "X-Set-Cookie-SameSite", "X-Set-Cookie-Raw"},
        AllowMethods:  []string{echo.GET, echo.HEAD, echo.PUT, echo.PATCH, echo.POST, echo.DELETE},
    }))
```